# Ошибка: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, java, android

Пытаюсь передать данные на сервер, но вылазит данная ошибка в логе. После этого её в логе появляется ошибка Fatal Error: AsynkTask#1. Вот собственно лог:

```
`E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: create new thread
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: new thread created
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: update thread list
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15417/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: interp stack at 0x5ed9c000
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15417/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: created from interp
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: start new thread
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=13: exiting
07-21 14:49:00.343 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet W/dalvikvm: threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4193a9a8)
07-21 14:49:00.344 15140-15417/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=14: notify debugger
07-21 14:49:00.344 15140-15417/avdeewkiril.paybillet D/dalvikvm: threadid=14 (AsyncTask #2): calling run()
07-21 14:49:00.345 15140-15409/avdeewkiril.paybillet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at avdeewkiril.paybillet.MainActivity$NewBillet.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:242)
                                                                           at avdeewkiril.paybillet.MainActivity$NewBillet.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:219)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838) 
`
```

Вот сам код:

```
class NewBillet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Бронирование биллета");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String[]args){
            String pay_status = "no";
            String real_date_from = args[0];
            String real_date_back = args[1];
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_from", real_date_from));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("real_date_back", real_date_back));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pay_status", pay_status));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_new_ticket, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try{
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCES);
                if (success == 1){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tickets.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void Bronirovat(View v)
    {
        TextView dateFrom =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        TextView dateBack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
        new NewBillet().execute(dateFrom.getText().toString(), dateBack.getText().toString());
    }
```

Лог ссылается на строчку `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());`
На сколько я понял, ошибка кроется в том, что JSON не может конвертировать строку в нужный тип. 
Вот класс JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {

// Making HTTP request
        try {

// check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
// request method is POST
// defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
// request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format (params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e ("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString ());
        }

// try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject (json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

// return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Также прикрепляю php, так как думаю, что возможно начудил где-то там:

```
   <?php
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['real_date_from']) && isset($_POST['real_date_back']) && isset($_POST['pay_status'])) {

    $real_date_from = $_POST['real_date_from'];
    $real_date_back = $_POST['real_date_back'];
    $pay_status = $_POST['pay_status'];

    require 'db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bus_order(real_date_from, real_date_back, pay_status) VALUES('$real_date_from', '$real_date_back', '$pay_status')");

    if ($result) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

[image: Скрин бд]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка говорит сама за себя, ваш `JSONObject json` не JSON вовсе..

1. Проверьте правильно ли выглядит ваш url
2. Если правильно, то посмотрите какой тип данных он возвращает
3. Вот таким образом строки не стоит сравнивать  `if(method == "POST")`. Строки как и любые другие объекты сравнивают через `if(stringA.equals(stringB))`
4. Под дебагом посмотрите где именно падает у Вас в `makeHttpRequest`

Comment: А можно поподробней . Так как первое отпадает, в браузере вводил данный url, все работает. Не подскажите, как можно посмотреть какой тип данных он возвращает?

Comment: Нашел ошибку, была в конфиге php файла. Неправильно были введены логин и пароль.